# Oracle Database 12c Connectivity issue

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle12c

I have successfully installed oracle 12c on my oracle linux 6.5 machine and i was able to connect to database using the following commands:

```
$ Sqlplus / as sysdba
  Connected to idle instance
SQL> startup;
SQL> Connected
```

But now the problem is when i am trying to start my database using 'startup' command it is giving me this error message

> ORA-04031: unable to allocate 760 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","unknown object","sga heap(1,0)","ksdhng: els blkrs cache")

I have looked up for this error on internet and solution i am getting is to alter the shared pool size but i am unable to do so as i cannot connect to the database. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Oracle memory parameters before starting the database. You have over allocated memory.

Comment: Can you please tell me where i can find the file to update memory parameters

Answer (score 0):

@daniyal.bashir, could you post your memory related parameters from pfile or spfile and your machines ram and "vmstat 1 1" output? Error what you have mentioned is mostly related to memory and fastest option is to remove all the memory parameters from the pfile and set "memory_target=X number of bytes"

Thanks,
KK

Comment: problem solved i am able to connect to my database using the pfile, using this command: startup pfile= /path of pfile

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic but maybe someone find this useful.

If you played with `alter system set processes, sessions, transactions (etc.)` and now you get `ORA-04031: unable to allocate ...` because of too high values, the fastest fix is to go to the `spfilexe.ora` (or similar) and correct the values by hand.

But the `spfilexe.ora` file is binary, so you can't simply change one number with another!

Use this trick:
for: `*.sessions=30000` make a change this way: `*.sessions=00300`

The file size and the check sum will remain unchanged while you will be able to `startup` the database and correct the values with SQL queries later.

If something is stupid but works, it is not stupid, right? ;-)